# How to reference a Web Service after it is published to Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services

I developed a web service in Visual Studio 2015.  I tested the web service locally by using the WCF test client.  When I start the client, it displays this
[image]

To execute the service, I double click on get_homepage() and then I click on the invoke button.  The service executes and returns the required information.

Then, I published the web service up to Amazon Web Services using the AWS Publish wizard in Visual Studio 2015 (I installed the package earlier).  After the package uploads, AWS returns to me a public URL so I can reference the web service that I uploaded.  The url that AWS generated is http://webservicewmcw-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com.

If I enter http://webservicewmcw-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/Service1.svc?singleWsdl into the browser, a bunch of xml tags are returned but not the data I am looking for.

My question is, how do I call the get_homepage instance within the web service?

Comment: well.. checking the link, that's a wsdl returned. what did you expect? you mean this one? http://webservicewmcw-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/Service1.svc

Comment: Your root url also returns your directory structure. I hope you don't have secrets up there!!!

Comment: What I expect to receive back is data from the web service.  When I test the web service within Visual Studio and execute the get_homepage() method, the web service returns a string of data that says "What\'s my crap worth|This application will allow the user to use his/her device c" +   "amera to scan a product barcode and look up the value of the prodcut on Amazon a" +  "nd eBay based on the products barcode".  This is the data I need back when I call the web service from within a React app that I will be developing.  But I need to know how to call the web service before moving forward